# upgraded to 12.04 Boots straight into command line

Tags: gui

I just upgrader to 12.04 from 11.10. The install appeared to go well but the computer goes through the usual boot with splash but the goes to the command line without a GUI. How do I open the GUI and fix this issue?

Comment: Hey there! Welcome to askubuntu! Can you please give a little more information in order for us to help you more. What kind of hardware do you have? Is this a laptop or desktop? Do you know what kind of Graphics Card is being used within the system?

Comment: yup along with above comment try this also . login there and type ** sudo start lightdm ** :)

Comment: @raja.genupula I agree that this could hypothetically work; you shoudl try typing `sudo start lightdm`

Comment: does your computer has an ATI video card? and if so, do you have installed the propietary drivers?
if so, try using: sudo amdconfig --uninstall         
if not, press shift when booting to call GRUB and go to recovery mode.

Answer (score -2):

There appears to be issues with the nouveau drivers. I suggest reinstalling 11.10 as I couldn't get 12.04 to work on my system either.